# How to parallelize model training with PySpark

Tags: machine-learning, pyspark, parallel-processing

I have a large Spark DataFrame (it doesn't fit in memory) that contains data for multiple devices.

For each device there are multiple rows, and the columns contain features and a target. Here is what it looks like with dummy data:

```
| DeviceID | Feature 1 | Feature 2 | Target |
|----------|-----------|-----------|--------|
|        A |         1 |         2 |      3 |
|        A |         2 |         4 |      6 |
|        B |         1 |         2 |      3 |
|        B |         2 |         4 |      6 |
|        C |         1 |         2 |      3 |
|        C |         2 |         4 |      6 |
```

I want to fit one linear model for each device, and I would like to parallelize this training to speed up computation.

With the data above, I would end up with 3 models: one for device A, one for device B, one for device C.

Can this be achieved with PySpark?

Using joblib Parallel/delayed doesn't work because spark dataframes can't be serialized.

Comment: There are a number of ways to parallelize ML models with spark, but I think the simplest out-of-the-box solution is to use Sparks inbuilt ML models https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-guide.html Docs on linear regression here https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-classification-regression.html#linear-regression

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can achieved in PySpark. Some ML algorithms already work out of the box, i.e., they are already parallelized using different worker nodes. See these algorithms here : https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-classification-regression.html

What you need to do is divide the data based on DeviceID and train them in separate linear models. If you like to parallelize the training for 3 different linear models, open 3 different spark sessions and train them on device specific data.

Answer (score 0):

The types of model trainings mentioned by other answers are if you want to train *one big model* on all of your data. What you are trying to do is train many small models. To do that, what you should do is group the DataFrame by `DeviceID` and pass each sub dataset to a PandasUDF for training.

[Here](https://www.databricks.com/blog/2021/04/06/fine-grained-time-series-forecasting-at-scale-with-facebook-prophet-and-apache-spark-updated-for-spark-3.html) is a blog post that describes how to do this at scale. Ignore the part about prophet, you can use any ML model you like that works on pandas DataFrames. Note that Spark parallelizes the training so each dataset is trained on a separate executor.

[Documentation on PandasUDF](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/sql-pyspark-pandas-with-arrow.html#pandas-udfs-aka-vectorized-udfs)

Answer (score 0):

1. Initialize a **SparkContext**
2. Create individual dataframes corresponding to each of your DeviceID (use filter method) and create a list like
   **category_data_list = [category_A_data, category_B_data, category_C_data]**.

3)Define a function to train model on each of these categories of data

4)Use **parallelize** function and pass the category_data_list.

5)Repeat the above steps for predictions as well.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using [applyInPandas](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.GroupedData.applyInPandas.html) which does a nice job parallelizing a task based on a group by of one or several columns the original dataframe.